# Downloading elevations in different resolutions using worldwind

Tags: elevation, download, worldwind

I'm new in NASA worldwind and I want to download elevation with NASA worldwind and then use it offline. I have a bbox as follow:

```
int minX = 20;
int maxX = 80;
int minY = -80;
int maxY = 80;
```

I'm using as follow, But I don't get the results I want:

```
Angle minLat = Angle.fromXY(maxX, minY);
Angle maxLat = Angle.fromXY(minX, maxY);
Angle minLon = Angle.fromXY(minX, minY);
Angle maxLon = Angle.fromXY(maxX, maxY);

Sector sector = new Sector(minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon);

ArrayList<LatLon> latlons = new ArrayList();

double[] buffer = new double[]{0.0};

double[] resolutions = new double[]{0.05235987755982988, ...};
double[] elevations = this.elevationModel.getElevations(sector, latlons, resolutions, buffer);
```

How can I download elevations in a bbox in different resolutions?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using worldwind to download elevation data?

Comment: @JonasV I'm developing Worldwind open source project and I want to cache some elevations and user can use it in offline mode.